# C : Convert signed to unsigned

Tags: c, signed, unsigned-integer

Actually I've (probably) a "simple" problem. So I don't know how to cast a signed integer to an unsigned integer.

My code :

```
signed int entry = 0;
printf("Decimal Number : ");
scanf("%d", &entry);
unsigned int uEntry= (unsigned int) entry;
printf("Unsigned : %d\n", uEntry);
```

If I send the unsigned value to the console (see my last code line), I always get back an signed integer.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards, pro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
printf("Unsigned : %u\n", uEntry);
//                 ^^
```

You must use the `%u` specifier to tell the `printf` runtime that the `uEntry` is an `unsigned int`. If you use `%d` the `printf` function will expect an `int`, thus reinterpret your input back to a signed value.

Comment: Hi Kenny, Thanks for your answer. If I set the %u specifier, I will get for -13 an unsigned value of 4294967283. What's the problem. Thanks.

Comment: There's no problem. That is the unsigned representation of the bits of your variable.

Comment: @pro: When your format specifier doesn't match the type of the value you are printing, the behavior is undefined and the results are meaningless. I.e. when you print `-13` with `%u` the results are meaningless. As well as your original attempt to print an unsigned value with `%d`. Always use the correct format specifier, if you want your output to make sense: `%u` for `unsigned int`, `%d` for `signed int`.

Comment: @pro: -13 is out of range for `unsigned int`.  When you convert an out-of-range number to an unsigned type, it is brought into range by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value of the type - in this case, `UINT_MAX + 1`, which is 4294967296 on your platform, is added to -13 to give 4294967283.

Answer (score 1):

Append these two lines at the end of your code, and you would understand what is going on.

```
printf("entry: signed = %d, unsigned = %u, hex = 0x%x\n", entry, entry entry);
printf("uEntry: signed = %d, unsigned = %u, hex = 0x%x\n", uEntry,uEntry,uEntry);
```

Comment: While it may be informative in explaining how your particular implementation works, both of these calls result in undefined behavior. You have to provide the correct types to `printf` according to what you specified in the format string in order for the results to be well-defined.