# how to convert an unsigned int to NSString?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, unsigned-integer

I have an unsinged int having value of -10,
now I want to convert it into `NSString`.

In simply we do as, in objective-c, iphone programming

```
int x = 10;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
NSLog(@"My String is %@",str);
```

I will show console output as 10

but if it is something like

```
unsigned int x = -10;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
NSLog(@"My String is %@",str);
```

Then the output will be same, not the -10,

how can I do proper conversion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%u` instead of `%d`. It is similar to [C : Convert signed to unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825194/c-convert-signed-to-unsigned/).

Answer (score 11):

Did you ever ask yourself what **unsigned** means?

It is always >= 0. -10 is not a valid value for an unsigned variable.

Comment: @veer: may be that because of self conversion

Comment: %d interprets the value as *signed*. Use %u for unsigned (which will give 4294967286 as this corresponds to the internal representation of the -10). Please also check out the link in @KennyTM's answer.

Comment: then what is solution for my problem sir?

Comment: @Eiko, but now how can I show an unassigned value on label using NSString

Comment: Use *int* and *%d* for values that are negative or positive. *unsigned* and *%u* are for positive values only.

Comment: Then say clearly what you want to achieve and we can give you the solution.

Comment: int x = 0;
if(condition true){x++;}else{x--;}, when it will do -- again and again, value will go negative, then how to show that on label?

Comment: int x = -10; NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];   will give you "-10". If it doesn't, please copy-paste the real complete code.

Answer (score 3):

An *unsigned* integer can't have a value of -10.

Comment: then how to save minus values?

Comment: By using a *signed* `int` (i.e. just a plain old `int`).